# Time Complexity of these nested loops

Tags: loops, time-complexity

I have come across several posts with regards to the time complexity of a nested for loop being `O(n^2)`. Is it still applicable for the two cases I have mentioned below?

Case 1: Second for loop doesn't have an increment of 1 but is instead multiplied with 2 for each iteration

```
for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
{
  for(j = 1; j <= n; j = j*2)
  {
   // Some code
  }
}
```

Case 2: Second for loop starts with `n/2` and increments by 1 for each iteration.

```
for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
{
  for(j = n/2; j <= n; j++)
  {
   // Some code
  }
}
```

In both of these case, `n` is some integer. I thought the time complexity in either case was `O(n^2)`. Is that the actual time complexity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The top one is O(n log(n)) and the bottom one is quadratic, O(n^2).

Both outer loops are obviously linear, so the issue boils down to determining the complexity of the inner loops and multiplying them with their respective outer loop complexity.

For the top inner loop, `j` is repeatedly doubled, creating the sequence 1, 2, 4, 8, 16... The total iterations of this inner loop is log2 of `n`, similar to binary search (or, dividing `n` by half repeatedly).

For the bottom inner loop, iterations run from `n/2` to `n`. The constant factor of 2 is ignored so this is the same as iterating from `0` to `n`, or linear.

Comment: Thank you so much!